# Error in transaction processing when using SetPaymentsOptionsRequest

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on integrating PayPal into a client's ecommerce site. Using the sandbox, we got everything working fine. I now need to add in SetPaymentOptionsRequest to prevent the user from changing his shipping address (they enter it on our site, so they can't change it at PayPal due to different shipping costs calculated on our site). It appears to work fine, but I get a 3005 error when logging into the PayPal sandbox site to confirm the transaction. Below is the relevant code (C#):

```
public string MakeChainedPayment(params params) {
  var request = new PayRequest {
    requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_us"),
    actionType = "CREATE",
    cancelUrl = this._cancelUrl,
    currencyCode = this._currencyCode,
    returnUrl = this._returnUrl,
    ipnNotificationUrl = this._ipnNotificationUrl
  };

  // Some code to generate receivers, not important for this problem, I don't think

  var response = this._paymentService.Pay(request);

  switch (response.paymentExecStatus) {
    // This always returns "CREATED", as I'd want, so good up to here.
    case "CREATED":
      // If I leave this code out, PayPal works fine, but I need 
      // this part to do the shipping address verification.

      var p = new SetPaymentOptionsRequest();
      p.senderOptions = new SenderOptions();
      p.senderOptions.addressOverride = false;
      p.senderOptions.shippingAddress = new ShippingAddressInfo {
        // Setting from params: city, country, zip, state, street1, street2
      };

      p.payKey = response.payKey;
      p.requestEnvelope = request.requestEnvelope;

      SetPaymentOptionsResponse r = _paymentService.SetPaymentOptions(payOptsReq);
      break;

      // This always retuns r.error.Count = 0, r.responseEnvelope.ack = "SUCCESS",
      // so I think I'm good to go.
  }

  if (this._useSandbox) {
    return string.Concat("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=", response.payKey);
  }

    return string.Concat("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=", response.payKey);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was what I was passing in for the country; I was sending in "USA", and it should be "US".

Comment: Of course, my response was all fine, but apparently not completely fine before I made that change. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal returns this message when your Paypal account's email address has not been verified. To verify your Paypal Email account, please follow the following steps:

Log into your Paypal Account. You should be in the “Overview” tab.

Click on your Email address, under “Business account overview”, you will be taken to a Web page listing your Paypal Email addresses.

Select your Primary Adress.

Click on the “Confirm” button.

Follow the rest of the Paypal instructions.

Comment: Is this for the buyer's email address or the seller's?

Comment: The merchant account has to be verified to receive payments.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem; I'm using sandbox test accounts, and all of my accts say verified in account details > profile. Plus, if I leave out `SetPaymentOptionsResponse r =  _paymentService.SetPaymentOptions(payOptsReq);`, payment works fine.

Comment: So to confirm, when you say the error occurs when logging into the PayPal sandbox site to confirm the transaction, you are logging into the sandbox account as opposed to your developer account?

Comment: Correct; I'm logging in to the sandbox account that is the buyer/sender.

Comment: If you want to post the email address of the sandbox account I can have a look at the back end.

Comment: Sure, thanks; it's joe@solehubtest.com. Using chained payments, the primary receiver acct is joegoogle@solehubtest.com, and secondary receiver acct is kolby-facilitator@solehub.com.

Comment: the 3005 error in the sandbox environment is a general error at best. In my original answer I assumed you had gone live and were receiving this error. It appears that the facilitator account is a business account but Pro is not enabled. I think this might be the issue. With your permission I will attempt to upgrade the account to Pro.

Comment: As long as there's no cost or anything like that, please do.

Comment: no cost in the sandbox environment, However, you should be aware that if this fixes your issue, you will likely face it again when you go live. In the live environment PayPal Payments Pro is a value-added product and carries a monthly charge.

Comment: No luck; I enabled pro on the facilitator account, but I still got the same error when adding the SetPaymentOptions call.

Comment: Can you receive email at either of the email addresses you submitted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55148/discussion-between-keving-and-joe).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem was I was sending in "USA" for the country instead of "US". It'd be nice if the SetPaymentOptions call threw an error into the response to that regard.